# Best location to store config, plugins for my OS X application

Tags: macos, desktop-application

I'm programming an OS X application and would like to know what is considered to be the best location to store application data like config-files and plugins for my program into.

The configs aren't in defaults format since I also deploy this application on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in your app's subfolder within the Application Support directory is where stuff like is expected to be stored. Apple provides a nice function in their documentation for getting a standardized `NSURL` for your Application Support directory.

Extracted from [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html):

```
- (NSURL*)applicationDirectory
{
    NSString* bundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSFileManager*fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL*    dirPath = nil;

    // Find the application support directory in the home directory.
    NSArray* appSupportDir = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    if ([appSupportDir count] > 0)
    {
        // Append the bundle ID to the URL for the
        // Application Support directory
        dirPath = [[appSupportDir objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:bundleID];

        // If the directory does not exist, this method creates it.
        // This method is only available in OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0 or later.
        NSError*    theError = nil;
        if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                   attributes:nil error:&theError])
        {
            // Handle the error.

            return nil;
        }
    }

    return dirPath;
}
```

You can call the subpath within `NSApplicationDirectory` anything you want, but they recommend using your bundle identifier, as seen in the example above.